# When something unexpected happens in a film, can it be called a "reversal"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Let's say that we're watching a film in which a good guy is trying to track down a serial killer. At the end of the film we suddenly realise the the good guy *is* the serial killer! Can we call this a "reversal" in the sense that it is something not expected,or the opposite of what was expected? If not, what is the suitable word?

Comment: Or _irony_ could be another way to say it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the proper word is *plot twist*. Which in your example is pretty well defined by the abrupt change of what one would expect from the storyline to be like.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the word you're looking for is "reveal". Because the information is there all the time, it just hasn't been revealed to the audience yet.

Answer (score 0):

It means the roles of good guy vs. bad guy were switched (reversed). In film it is usually unexpected, but in general usage depends on context.